# string index out of bound exception, String index out of range

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

So, I was writing a simple program to enter a string and count the total no. of m. 
So, here's my code

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if((str.charAt(i)=='m'))
        {
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of m is "+count);
```

where `n=str.length();`
and str is a string which I had taken but there this error which keeps coming

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at javaapplication.JavaApplication.main(JavaApplication.java:28
Java Result: 1
```

what's this error and how to remove it?

Comment: The `count++` should be in the `if` block, not the `else` block, since you are trying to count the number of m's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A String of `length() == n` has valid indices from 0 to n-1;

Change

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have the following array of **length 7**:

```
-----------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  <-- Array index
-----------------------------
|10 |20 |30 |40 |50 |60 |70 |  <-- Array values
-----------------------------
```

A for loop of `for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)` in this case will loop **8 times** iterating from index **0 to 7**.

But the array element at index **7** does not exist, hence giving `outOfBoundsException`.

Where as a for loop of `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` will loop **7 times** iterating from **0 to 6**.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Strings are indexed from 0 to StringName.length() - 1. Since you are iterating through StringName().length -- you are actually going right outside the "bounds" of the string which is causing the error. You need to make sure your indices are correct in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Characters in String variable start at 0 index.

Also if you want to count the total appearance of small letter `m`, move your `count++` to your `if block statement`.

```
 n=str.length() - 1;
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if((str.charAt(i)=='m'))
            {
                  count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The total number of m is "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

charat works with index(works from  to n-1), but in your for you get to condition where you have i=n, in this case charat throws exception because it does not have that index in array