# String index out of bound error

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

The bellow class contain a method `fromRomanToArabic ()` in this method I'm trying to convert a Arabic number to Roman number. the method should act as follows:

- take the user String from the object
- itterate through the string
- add up the values associated with the characters. If the characters associated number is larger than the previous one, deduct the character value from the sum.

here is my code:

```
package romantoarabicnums;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class RomanToArabicNums {
    private static String userString;
    private static int userNumber;
    private static char letter;
    private static int letterNum;

    public RomanToArabicNums (String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

           if (s.charAt(i) == 'M' ||s.charAt(i) == 'D' ||s.charAt(i) == 'C' ||s.charAt(i) == 'X' ||
               s.charAt(i) == 'V' ||s.charAt(i) == 'I' ||s.charAt(i) == 'L') {
               userString += s.charAt(i);
           }
           else {throw new NumberFormatException("Only M,C,D,X,V and I allowed");}
        }
    }
    public RomanToArabicNums (int num) throws NullPointerException {
       if (num >= 1 && num <= 3999) {
           RomanToArabicNums.userNumber = num;
       }
       else {throw new NumberFormatException("numbers between 1 and 3999 only!");}
    }
    public RomanToArabicNums (char let, int num) {
        RomanToArabicNums.letter = let;
        RomanToArabicNums.letterNum = num;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RomanToArabicNums r2 = new RomanToArabicNums("MCMXCV");
        System.out.println("the arabic number is: " + r2.fromRomanToArabic());

    }
    /* convert Roman characters to Arabic numbers */
    public int fromRomanToArabic () {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= userString.length(); i++) {
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'M') {
                    sum += 1000;
                }
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'D') {
                    if (userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M') {
                        sum -= 500;
                    } else {
                        sum += 500;
                    }
                }
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'C') {
                    if (userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'D') {
                        sum -= 100;
                    } else {
                        sum += 100;
                    }
                }
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'L') {
                    if (userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'D'
                            || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'C') {
                        sum -= 50;
                    } else {
                        sum += 50;
                    }
                }
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'X') {
                    if (userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'D'
                            || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'C' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'L') {
                        sum -= 10;
                    } else {
                        sum += 10;
                    }
                }
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'V') {
                    if (userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'D'
                            || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'C' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'L'
                            || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'X') {
                        sum -= 5;
                    } else {
                        sum += 5;
                    }
                }
                /**/
                if (userString.charAt(i) == 'I') {
                    if (userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'D'
                            || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'C' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'L'
                            || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'X' || userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'V') {
                        sum -= 1;
                    } else {
                        sum += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return sum;

    }
}
```

and here is the error:
[image]

NOTE: I think that the error is due to number of string elements being less that the steps in the for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string index out of bound exception, String index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777630/string-index-out-of-bound-exception-string-index-out-of-range)

Comment: What's the reason to adding Arabic to Roman conversion functionality to the class called `RomanToArabicNums`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Jens' and Andy's answers you should actually check for `i + 1 < userString.length()`, since you use `userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M'`.

This will also cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you're at the index of the last character.

Note that you'll need to handle the last character accordingly or keep `i < userString.length()` and add a check if `i + 1` exceeds the string's length wherever you use `userString.charAt(i + 1)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! this almost solved the problem. I'm getting a return int value of 1990. for MCMXCV it should return 1995

Comment: @zamzam As I said you need to apply your logic to the last character seperatly after the loop since you break out of it too early.

Answer (score 2):

So strings are Zero bases, you have to run your Loop until: `i < userString.length()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++) {
```

And theree are many more Errors where you get a character out of the length of your string.

Comment: @zamzam No not same error. But you have a lot of Errors with index in strings.

Comment: @Jens He'll still get an IndexOutOfBoundsException due to charAt(i+1)..

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Javadoc of [`String.charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

> [throws] `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.

So anywhere you call `userString.charAt`, you need to ensure that the index meets these conditions:

- `i <= userString.length()` should be `i < userString.length()`. This means that all `userString.charAt(i)` calls succeed;
- All of the calls to `userString.charAt(i + 1)` require a prior check that `i + 1 < userString.length()`, e.g.

  ```
  if (i + 1 < userString.length() && userString.charAt(i + 1) == 'M') {
  ```

  Logically, these calls are checking the "next character". By checking the value of `i + 1` first, this check is basically saying:

  ```
  if ((there is a next character) AND (the next character is 'M')) {
  ```

Comment: It's not the only problem with the code. He also calls userString.charAt(i + 1) at different places in his code, so even if he fixes the for, it will still throw that exception.

Comment: @zamzam it is *not* the same error, only the same *kind* of error. If you look carefully at the stack trace before and after changing the loop guard, you will see that the exception is thrown on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't got this at all. But you do the following in your method:

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= userString.length(); i++)
```

You should do this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `userString.charAt(i + 1)` in a loop where `i <= userString.length()`

so there are 2 indexes that are going to be out of bound
`i == n - 1` and `i == n`.

change loop definition from

```
for (int i = 0; i <= userString.length(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < userString.length() - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! this almost solved the problem. I'm getting a return int value of 1990. for MCMXCV it should return 1995

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code. One is obvious - you're looping `for (int i = 0; i <= userString.length(); i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++)`. The second one is more hidden. You don't check if `i + 1 < userString.length()` before calling `charAt(i+1)`. Fixing those two mistakes will let you convert valid Roman numbers.

**One more thing**. The class called `RomanToArabic` isn't the best place to convert `Arabic` to `Roman`. Consider refactoring the name of your class to `RomanArabicConverter` or divide your logic to two separate classes and provide one class that would `aggregate` both of them.