# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 69

Tags: java, jsp

```
String AlphaNumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0; i<8; i++)
{
    int index = (int)(AlphaNumeric.length() * Math.random());
    sb.append(AlphaNumeric.charAt(index));
}
String str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: you are trying to access the 70th character of a String which is clearly less than 70 characters.

Comment: @san, You need to use AlphaNumeric.length() - 1 instead of AlphaNumeric.length() to generate the random values in your approach.

Comment: I don't think the exception is thrown in the code above.

Comment: If i dont miss something the given code should work fine and will never produce the given error as `Math.random()` will always return a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. So index should be between `0` and `AlphaNumeric.length() -1`. The issue must be some where else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string index out of bound exception, String index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777630/string-index-out-of-bound-exception-string-index-out-of-range)

Comment: I think this question could be deleted, because the problem is obvious if you simply output `index`. So what is the question, actually?

Comment: @U.Windl is it obvious how 69 is generated?

Comment: @Andy Turner: I doubt the code displayed is the code that triggered the problem. The user should add an output statement as suggested to show the numbers that are actually assigned to index. Maybe the output rings some bell for the user or here...

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the error is attempting to access some index that does not exist.

Given that `String alphaNumeric` has some length, it is possible to use the Random class to find a value within the range.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

final int len = alphaNumeric.length();

// generate 8 random characters, adding each random character
//  to the collector
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  // get a random value within the range, 0...N exclusive
  int index = rnd.nextInt(len);
  sb.append(alphaNumeric.charAt(index));
}
```

The use of the `Random` allows selecting a random value within a given range.

[javadoc for Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-):

> **public int nextInt(int bound)**
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All bound possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

[Example may be seen at this link](https://ideone.com/zvngQa)